# How to work with one array in two methods

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can i insert value in array in one method and work with this full of value array in other method.

```
-(void)firstMethod {

      NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      ../// add some value in array.
}

-(void)secondMethod {


       ..// here i want to work with array which consist of value from first method.

 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can  create one instance of `NSMutableArray` and use that in the both method.

```
@interface ViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *array;
}
@end
```

Now access this array in both methods

```
-(void)firstMethod {

    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:@"Hello"];
}

-(void)secondMethod {
    if (array) {
        [array addObject:@"World"];//Add object that you want
    }
    else {
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [array addObject:@"World"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome mate :) Happy Coding :)

Comment: I test your solution and in the second method NSLog said that array (null) but previously in first method i add CGPoint

Comment: check edit of second method , now you will not get nil.

Comment: Sorry it's my fault your solution works perfectly, in the first time i make a mistake in and write NSMutableArray array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `NSMutableArray` property

```
@interface ViewController () 
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *array;
@end
```

create instance in `init` method

```
- (instancetype)init{
    if(self == [super init]) {
       _array = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)firstMethod {
     [self.array addObject:@"obj1"];
}

-(void)secondMethod {
    [self.array addObject:@"obj2"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN USE BELOW CODE:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue;
_concurrentQueue= dispatch_queue_create("any String", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

- (NSArray *)secondMethod
{
    __block NSArray *array;
    dispatch_sync(self.concurrentQueue, ^{
        array= [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
    });
    return array;
}

- (void)firstMethod:(NSString *)str
{
    if (str) {
        dispatch_barrier_async(self.concurrentQueue, ^{
            [array addObject:str];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           //Do some asynchronous work
        });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: NSArray is thread safe . There is no point in using the queues for NSArray.

Comment: you shud add that to your answer. Stating code only will not help  anyone. You should add relevant explanation to the answer.

Comment: NO, you should do it, I have no knowledge of using the queues for thread safety.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri To gain the knowledge of thread safety you should read this article: https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1 It will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers suggest you to declare array as property. But usually it's more clear to just pass needed data as arguments to another method:

```
-(void)firstMethod {

  NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  ../// add some value in array.

  [self secondMethod:array];

}

-(void)secondMethod:(NSArray *)array {


   ..// here i want to work with array which consist of value from first method.

}
```

Comment: Thank you, i try this solution too!